# Delayed email, server side using dovecot/postfix

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

Alternative title:  How to delay a mail queue in postfix for a certain user.

I am planning to build a solution.  At first it would be I would create a separate email address for queuing.  Use a client to send the email from that address.  The queue on that email would be paused (not processing) and then create a job/script or something(separate question) to relay a `sendmail -q` to postfix to release the queue.

How do I make the queue stay in a delayed state so this is possible.  I do not wish to stop the service and restart it at certain times since that would disable all other email.

Comment: This sounds like mail delivery. What does it have to do with dovecot? Shouldn't this be a Postfix/sendmail/exim/qmail question?

Comment: Very quite possibly.  I am still a little confused on this structure.  I am afraid I am still at the follow the instructions closely stage of my linux email delivery structures.  I am using Postfix.  I will update the question

Comment: Forget dovecot, it doesn't matter here. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: All typical delayed email solution require the client to be active.  Since I am between different OS/computers I can't rely on the client.  I am trying to get a better solution for delayed send.  I am aware I can use squirrelmail, but I would prefer a solution that doesn't require an active web server.  If there is an available add-in/project that would be wonderful.  I don't mean to re-invent the wheel.  Reason 2:  I might learn something

Comment: Why do you want to delay mail in the first place? Mail servers are designed to get rid of the mail as soon as possible.

Comment: What is the purpose and goal of what you are trying to achieve?  Your question is not clear. Are you trying to schedule email delivery? If so, that is a task for the mailing manger and not for the MTA.  Are you trying to prevent users from getting email asap?  If so, then you may have to set your MTA to only run the queue every so often.  If you clarify your goal, I am sure someone here can help you.

Comment: Oh.  I am just forgetful and somethings I do are time sensitive.  My email needs to be out a 5pm and I am emailing it to A.  I email B and say do you have any revisions for this email I am sending to A.  B will send corrections or sometimes forget to respond or not bother (sometimes the case in mass forwards).  Unless I stop it I want that email going out at 5pm.  If B responds then I log in and kill the email.

Comment: All of these are use cases of MUAs, not MTAs.

Comment: MUAs/MTAs.  No idea what they are, but I am sure google does.  I appreciate the terms.  Often you just need to know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instruct postfix via  header_checks to hold emails with specific subjects or headers and then have a cron job that would release those emails at specific intervals/time.

So you would put this in your postfix configuration:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and then create the header_checks file an put:

```
/^From: "snailmail/ HOLD
```

then a cronjob would have to scan the mails that are on hold and release them.